# usdzConvert command not found error - WWDC 19

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

I'm trying to use command line to convert my .obj object to .usdz and enrich it with diffuse color as it mentioned in WWDC 19 [Working with USD](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/602). but I get `command not found: usdzconvert`.
That's the code

```
usdzconvert myObject.obj -diffuseColor 0.0,0.59,0.59
```

does anyone know what is the problem, or if there is any requirement to use this command.

P.S. I'm on macOS 10.15 Beta, I also have Xcode 11 beta installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `usdzconvert` command on macOS 10.15 Beta you need to first download [usdz Tools](https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/) from the bottom of the page and after extracting the zip file, use the **USD.command** file, which opens a terminal to access usdz commands.

You may also need to set your **PATH** and **PYTHONPATH** variables as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<PATH_TO_USDPYTHON>/USD
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_USDPYTHON>/USD
```

Make sure to check the readme file included with the package for more details.

Comment: Yes, That't true, it was also mentioned in the video, I realised it after I watched it again. Thanks.

Comment: So if my usdpython folder is inside Applications folder what will be the path?